# User harassment

Tags: discussion, rude-or-abusive, specific-user

[I removed an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71529229/1377002) because the OP decided to change the scope of the question, and it was no longer useful.

They then [wrote a rant about this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71529382/revisions).

I've since been contacted via an email by the OP to rant some more:

> Thanks asshole for deleting my post and downvoting my question. you showed that I was right and stack-overflow and open-source community is nothing more than bunch of virgin sitting behind a desk and jerking off. son of bitch.

What's the policy on harassment? I can block his emails but can we ban this user?

Comment: "OP decided to change the scope of the question" - Did they change the question **after** your answer? But the edit history of the referenced question is empty, and 10 minutes has been passed between posting the question and your answer. How it is possible?

Comment: @Tsyvarev OP wrote a comment under the answer that there aren't necessarily only 3 objects like they say in the question.

Comment: Because I won't stoop to their level. @Tom. That said: I did send him "a very English response" to his email, and then blocked him. It's not really worth the time.

Comment: Don't even reply to emails like that. It's just not worth it.

Comment: Ha. While I generally agree with that @Cerbrus this user came into to my home and insulted me. Can you imagine what working in a team with him would be like? Sometimes speaking up is the better option.

Comment: You raise a moderator flag about it and/or use the [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) page to alert staff. Forwarding them the email you received would also be useful.

Comment: A quick update. The OP basically started spamming me with hundreds of abusive emails. I blocked him, and my email provider (who are very cool) banned his email from ever getting through to me again. Thanks again to the mods here, and the advice.